# What does it mean to buflist netrw buffer?

Tags: buffers, netrw

I find there is one line `let g:netrw_bufsettings = 'noma nomod nu nobl nowrap ro'` in my `_vimrc` file. [Google](http://rebbemalachi.blogspot.com/2013/04/re-making-netrw-buffers-buflisted.html) says it could make

> netrw buffers buflisted

What does it mean to make "netrw buffers buflisted"? Can anyone explain what the line in the `_vimrc` file does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `g:netrw_bufsettings` option is what allows you to set options that vim will only apply to netrw buffers.  A buffer is essentially a file that is loaded in vim, whether it actually exists on your hard drive or not.  You can get a list of all these buffers using the `:ls` command.  When the `buflisted` option is set *(which can be done manually like so: `:set buflisted`)*, it means that the buffer will be listed in the output of `:ls` and will be included in the current buffer list.

For more help on the commands used here, see these resources:

- `:help 'buflisted'`
- `:help :ls`
- `:help :set`